# Equation in a table in R

Tags: r

I want a table like this and make it as a kable so I can make footnote:

[image]

but I didn't manage so I made a table latex like this :

```
$$

\begin{array}{lccccc} 
\hline
{Copula} & {Distribution} & {Parameter range} & {Complete dependence} & {Independence} \\
\hline
{Normal} & {C_{Normal} (u_1,u_2,\rho)=\Phi_{\rho}(\Phi^{-1}(u_1),\Phi^{-1}(u_2))} & {\rho\in(-1,1)} & {\rho=1,or -1} & {\rho=0} \\
\hline
{Student-t} & {C_t (u_1,u_2;\rho,d)=t_{\rho,d}(t^{-1}_d(u_1),t^{-1}_d(u_2))} & {\rho\in(-1,1)} & {\rho=1,or -1} & {\rho=0} \\
\hline
{Gumbel} & {C_{Gumbel} (u_1,u_2,\beta)=exp\{-[(-ln(u_1))^{\frac{1}{\beta}}+(-ln(u_2))^{\frac{1}{\beta}}]^{\beta}\}} & {\beta\in(0,1)} & {\beta=0} & {\beta=1} \\
\hline
{RG} & {C_{RG} (u_1,u_2,\alpha)=u_1+u_2-1+C_{Gumbel} (1-u_1,1-u_2,\alpha)} & {\alpha\in[1,\infty)} & {\alpha\rightarrow\infty} & {\alpha=1} \\
\hline
{Clayton} & {C_{Clayton} (u_1,u_2,\theta)=max((u_1^{-\theta}+u_2^{-\theta}-1)^{-\frac{1}{\theta}},0)} & {\theta\in[-1,\infty)\{0\}} & {\theta\rightarrow\infty} & {\theta \rightarrow 0} \\
\hline
{RC} & {C_{RC} (u_1,u_2,\alpha)=u_1+u_2-1+C_{Clayton} (1-u_1,1-u_2,\theta)} & {\theta\in[-1,\infty)\{0\}} & {\theta\rightarrow\infty} & {\theta \rightarrow 0} \\
\hline
\end{array}

$$
```

and it looks like this:

[image]

It's not bad until I found it's not easy to add footnotes since I used to make kable.

Is there any way I can add a footnote for it? or how can I convert it into a table so I can use kable to display it?

Comment: See https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf

Comment: i didn't find solution there